# Is there an implementation of MPI_AllReduce which handles sparse data better?

Tags: mpi

I need to synchronize intermediate solutions of an optimization problem solved distributively over a number of worker processors. The solution vector is known to be sparse.

I have noticed that if I use MPI_AllReduce, the performance is good compared to my own AllReduce implementation.

However, I believe, the performance can be further improved if AllReduce could communicate only the nonzero entries in the solution vector. I could not find any such implementation of AllReduce.

Any ideas?

It seems that MPI_type_indexed can not be used as the indices of the nonzero entries are not known in advance.

Comment: Why not measure the performance of your code and see if this particular reduction operation matters at all? This seems like premature optimization to me.

Comment: If you use derived data types, you have to roll your own reduction operators, which will disable all of the optimizations that go into most MPI implementations.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your suggestion. It seems that the solution vector is 1,355,191 entries 60-70% of them are zero. The MPI communication is the main bottleneck.

Comment: Yes Jeff that what I am worried about implementing my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may create another vector to store all the non-zero elements in the solution vector. Then use MPI_ALLReduce.